# How to cast sqlite json column to Spark string or struct?

Tags: java, python, sqlite, jdbc, pyspark

I have a sqlite database with columns saved as json, some are just arrays and some are array of objects
Data isn't too big, around 1 million rows in a table and another 6 million on another table. Now I would like to improve queries speed and extract this data into something indexed and more manageable

The problem is that spark treat json columns as BigDecimal and I don't know why or how to solve this, found some things but nothing helped.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Bad value for type BigDecimal : [56641575300, 56640640900, 56640564100, 56640349700, 18635841800, 54913035400, 6505719940, 56641287800, 7102147726, 57202227222, 57191928343, 18633330200, 57193578904, 7409778074, 7409730079, 55740247200, 56641355300, 18635857700, 57191972388, 54912606500, 6601960745, 57191972907, 56641923500, 56640256300, 54911965100, 45661930800, 55474245300, 7409541556, 7409694518, 56641363000, 56519446200, 6504106170, 57191975866, 56640736700, 55463741500, 56640319300, 56640861000, 54911965000, 56561401800, 6504731849, 24342836300, 7402491855, 22950414800, 6507741522, 6504199636, 7102381436, 57191895642, 18634536800, 57196623329, 7005988322, 56013334500, 18634278500, 57191983462, 7409545828, 57204194408, 56641031400, 56641436400, 6504659572, 36829162100, 24766932600, 8256434300]
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getBigDecimal(JDBC3ResultSet.java:196)
```

What I tried, is to load the sqlite driver and then open the db with `SQLContext`

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url='jdbc:sqlite:../cache/iconic.db', dbtable='coauthors', driver='org.sqlite.JDBC').load()
```

After spark complained about column type, I tried to cast it as string so it could be further parsed as json

```
schema = ArrayType(IntegerType())
df.withColumn('co_list', from_json(df['co_list'].cast(StringType()), schema))
```

But this throw same error as it didn't changed anything

Also I tried to set table schema from start, but seems like pyspark doesn't let me to do this

```
df = sqlContext.read.schema([...]).format('jdbc')...
# Throws
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'jdbc does not allow user-specified schemas.;'
```

The rows look like this

```
# First table
1   "[{""surname"": ...}]"  "[[{""frequency"": ""58123"", ...}]]"   74072   14586   null    null    null    "{""affiliation-url"":}"    "[""SOCI""]"    null    0   0   1

# Second table
505 "[{""surname"": ""Blondel"" ...}, {""surname"": ""B\u0153ge"" ..}, ...]"    "1999-12-01"    21  null    null    null    0
```

Hope there is a way.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, database should be loaded using jdbc reader and to customize casting of columns, you should pass a property to the driver

Here is the solution

```py
connectionProperties = { 
    "customSchema": 'id INT, co_list STRING, last_page INT, saved INT',
    "driver": 'org.sqlite.JDBC'
}

df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url='jdbc:sqlite:../cache/iconic.db', table='coauthors', properties=connectionProperties)
```

This way you have control over how spark internally map columns of database table.